# React Native TextInput focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I am fairly new in react native(  "react-native": "0.65.1"). When I tried to use TextInput component I get  ["No Command found with name "focus"][1].
I did not understood the problem.
Here my code:

```
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
<TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="Enter name"
            onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
            defaultValue={text}
          />
```

Can anybody help me for understanding the problem?
Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLdxK.png

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the native element in react native works differently.

1. First you need to create a `React.ref` that will hold the native element functions.
2. Then you pass that variable to your element

So to access the focus function of a textinput element you would do something like this

```js
//code before your return your jsx
const textInputRef = useRef({});
...
//your other variables and stuff
...
return (
    ....
    <TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="Enter name"
            onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
            defaultValue={text}
            ref={textInputRef}
          />
)
```

You may save yourself some debugging time if you verify that the focus function exists on your ref

```js
// one liner
textInputRef.current.focus.?()
//verbose
if(textInputRef.current.focus)
  textInputRef.current.focus
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did what you said and now I get No command found with name "blur" error.
```
-[RCTUIManager dispatchViewManagerCommand:commandID:commandArgs:]
     RCTUIManager.m:1132
__invoking__
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator() ```

Comment: Could u give me a link to what your code looks like